# Why The Image Is Not Being Rendered In Html Template Even Being Added To Static Files - Django?

Tags: python, html, django

I have tried using the image address in the normal HTML file, and it works great, but as I try to render the image with an HTML template with Django all it shows is just an image placeholder. And When I Inspect The Image Element It Has The Correct Src Attribute But Still It Doesn't Load.
Here Is The Peace Of HTML

```
 <h1>{{article.title}}</h1>
 <div class="box">
   <img src= "{{article.article_thumbnail_image_url}}" alt="Failed To Load Thumbnail Image">
 </div>
```

Here Is The Final HTML File After Render

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">


  </head>
  <body>


    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>






    <div class="wrapper">

        
<title>Demo article</title>

<div class="header">
    <h4>Current Reading Progress</h4>
  <div class="progress-container">
    <div class="progress-bar" id="myBar"></div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="box">

    <div class="box">


        <div>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <h1>Demo article</h1>
            <div class="box">

             <img src= "Capture_jOmt1vm.PNG" alt="Failed To Load Thumbnail Image">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class>

                <p class="font-weight-light">Hello World Hello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello World</p>

        </div>
        <p>Aug. 31, 2020, 1:03 p.m.</p>
        <h3><a href="/articles/">Articles</a></h3>

    </div>
<style>
     .header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* The progress container (grey background) */
.progress-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 8px;
  background: #ee6c4d;
}

/* The progress bar (scroll indicator) */
.progress-bar {
  height: 8px;
  background: #0077b6;
  width: 0%;
}
.box{
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 8px;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #4CAF50;
}

p {
  text-indent: 50px;
  text-align: justify;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #008CBA;
}

    </style>

    <script>
    window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

function myFunction() {
  var winScroll = document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  var height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  var scrolled = (winScroll / height) * 100;
  document.getElementById("myBar").style.width = scrolled + "%";
}

    </script>

</div>







    </div>
    <style>

    </style>
</body>
</html>
```

Here Is How I Passed The Static Files To Root Urls

```
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

And Here Is How The Static Files Are Configured In Settings.py

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (

    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'assets'),

)

MEDIA_URL = '/articles/templates/articles/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
```

Comment: Is there an error in the dev tools?

Comment: Here Is What Dev Tools Console Shows There Are Only 2 Errors

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
2
(index):1 Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.

​

Comment: did you try to add whitespaces to the template tags? This often causes errors when interpreting the code. {{  correct  }}  {{wrong}}

Comment: @Jonas Thank you bro but it still sucks   I retried  by giving space and relaunching server and refreshing page but it is not  working

Comment: can you please add the rendered html (source code) as well to your post and the source of your file

Comment: @Jonas Ok I am Doing So Plz Wait.

Comment: @Wajid_Hussain I mean the rendered source code, in your browser click right on the loaded page and investigate the sourcecode + copy/paste it, I want to see the final URL

Comment: Ok I am such n id*T

Comment: @Jonas I re edited

Comment: @Wajid_Hussain ok, and is `Capture_jOmt1vm.PNG` loaded by the browser as well? It doesn't seem like. So you have to fix your static settings I guess. Where do you store the image within your project? And how do your static url settings in settings.py look like?

Comment: here is how my static setting looks like
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (

    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'assets'),

)

MEDIA_URL = '/articles/templates/articles/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')

And All The Media Files Are Stored In A Folder Called Media Which Was Autogenerated By The Settings. py 
And Here Is How I added These To My Root Urls File


urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

Comment: @Jonas I Updated The Question Check The Last Part Again, And Thanks For Being Connected  For Long Time :)

Comment: @Wajid_Hussain and in which directory do you store `Capture_jOmt1vm.PNG` ?

Comment: @Jonas It is in two directories
/articles/templates/articles/
and the media folder

Comment: puh hmh, did you load your media and static in your html? `{% load static %}` `{% load media %} at the very top of your html file.

Comment: @Jonas I produce
``````

Comment: ```
TemplateSyntaxError at /
'media' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of:
admin_list
admin_modify
admin_urls
cache
i18n
l10n
log
static
tz
```

Comment: ah my bad, remove `load media`, try to figure out why the image from your media folder isn't loaded by the browser, it is either a bug in your settings.py or in the path. You can also check the `sources` sections in google chrome dev tools to debug it

Comment: ok! it's 1:23 Am in my country so bye and thanks soooooo much for giving you such important time will contact you letter if need help.

Comment: @Jonas, by the way, do I need to register the media folder as app in settings

Comment: @Jonas know that when i give my template a local url from google it loads perfectly

Comment: You dont need to register it as app. Yes, because the browser is not able to find the image in your projects root. This is most of the times due to a bug in the media/static settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Solution:***
When Ever Using A File Feild In Django And To Render These Files Dynamically  You Have  To Get The Path Where That File Is Located If You DO It By Just Passing The Name Of Variable Name Django Template Won't Be Able to Know Where The File Is Located. For Example `{{ model.variable }}`In This Manner, The Template Will Only Get The Name Of File Not The Full Path And  Will Try To Create Wierd Path Like

```
app/templates/file.html/yourfile
```

To Fix The Issue You Have To Use The Django's Built-in .url Method To Get Accurate Location Of Files Located In Static Files.

```
{{ model.variable.url}}
```